# Delegate not firing from singleton in viewcontroller

Tags: swift, delegates, swift4, protocols

I am storing a prizeArray in a singleton. I've defined a protocol and a delegate. If I create a class (other than a viewController) the delegate fires as expected when I change the value of the prizeArray. However, in my viewController I'm having trouble firing the delegate. Can you point to what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Here's the singleton AppData class

```
import Foundation

protocol AppDataDelegate {
    func didChange(_ prizeArray: Array<Prize>)
}

class AppData
{
    static let shared = AppData()
    var delegate: AppDataDelegate?
    var parsedPrizes:[Prize] = []
    
    private init() {}
    
    func changeThis(newArray: [Prize]) {
        parsedPrizes = newArray
        print("AppData got parsedPrizes")
        delegate?.didChange(newArray)
    }
}

import UIKit
import CoreData

class GameBoard: FPBViewController, AppDataDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AppData.shared.delegate = self
    }

    func didChange(_ prizeArray: Array<Prize>) {
        print("data via the delegate prizeArray: \(prizeArray.count)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any other class that uses `AppData`'s singleton delegate? If so, maybe that's why... you probably reassign another `ViewController` to that delegate and `GameBoard` stops listening.

**EDIT;** In order to be able to notify multiple classes, you'll need to keep multiple instances of those classes like so:

```
import Foundation

protocol AppDataDelegate {
    func didChange(_ prizeArray: Array<Prize>)
}

class AppData
{
    static let shared = AppData()
    var delegates: [AppDataDelegate] = [] <=========== notify every class that listens
    var parsedPrizes:[Prize] = []
    
    private init() {}
    
    func changeThis(newArray: [Prize]) {
        parsedPrizes = newArray
        print("AppData got parsedPrizes")

        delegates.forEach { delegate in <===========
            delegate.didChange(newArray)
        }
    }
}

import UIKit
import CoreData

class GameBoard: FPBViewController, AppDataDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AppData.shared.delegates.append(self) <===========
    }

    func didChange(_ prizeArray: Array<Prize>) {
        print("data via the delegate prizeArray: \(prizeArray.count)")
    }

    @IBAction func closeVC(_ sender: Any) {
        if let index = AppData.shared.delegates.firstIndex(where: { $0 === self }) {
            AppData.shared.delegates.remove(at: index)
        }
    
        // -------------------------------------------
    
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. Can I not have more than 1 ViewController listening to the delegate?

Comment: Sure you can! Just create an array of `AppDataDelegate`, like so; `var delegates: [AppDataDelegate] = []`

Comment: I take it you mean in the Singleton. But if I do that then the changeThis function breaks. Can you show me an example? Thanks.

Comment: If I append to the array as suggested in viewDidLoad, that works. However, if the viewController disappears and then loads again, I get multiple notifications of the delegate because I've appended it.

Comment: That makes sense, because you probably don't remove the Instance of your vc when it dismisses

Comment: Any suggestion on that?

Comment: I updated my answer. I've added the `closeVC` button action, which removes the instance of your current ViewController from the `delegates` array, before it dismisses it.